# Python writing nested loop to file

Tags: for-loop, nested-loops, python-3.6, file-writing

I am trying to print out and write to a file a nested loop, but I fail the second part. It won't write to a file like a nested loop, but writes in a straight line. How can I solwe the problem?

```
def valjastaarv():
    rida = 12
    koht = 12
    iste_rida = 3
    iste_koht = 2

    f = open('tulemus.txt', 'w') 
    for i in range (1,int(koht)+1):
        for j in range (1,int(rida)+1):
            print(j, end = " ")
            f.write(str(i))
        print()
    f.close()

valjastaarv()
```

Comment: write a newline at the end of the first loop

Answer (score 2):

You need a newline `\n` each time you want to start a new line. Here's the code that works properly:

```py
def valjastaarv():
    rida = 12
    koht = 12
    iste_rida = 3
    iste_koht = 2

    f = open('tulemus.txt', 'w') 
    for i in range (1,int(koht)+1):
        for j in range (1,int(rida)+1):
            print(j, end = " ")
            f.write(str(j)+' ')
        print()
        f.write('\n')
    f.close()

valjastaarv()
```